# How to remove certain items from an array

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to get a list of all Apps plus their versions using mdfind:

```
function get_mac_apps_info {
    local list_apps=()
    local app_version
    local plist_info_app_path
    local plist_field="CFBundleName"

    readarray -d '' list_apps < <(mdfind -0 "kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle")

    for index in "${!list_apps[@]}"
         do [[ ${list_apps[$index]} =~ '^(?!.*\(Parallels\)).*' ]] && unset -v 'list_apps[$index]'
     done

        for app_path in "${list_apps[@]}"; do

        plist_info_app_path="$app_path/Contents/Info.plist"

        if [[ -f "$plist_info_app_path" ]]; then

            app_version="$(get_version_from_plist "$app_path" 2>/dev/null)"
            app_name="$(get_field_from_plist "$app_path" "$plist_field" 2>/dev/null)"
            if [[ $app_version ]]; then
                echo "$app_version;$app_name"
            fi
        fi

    done
}
```

Thing is Parallels Desktop is installed and gets a lot of entries like these when populating the mdfind array:

```
/Users/user-test/Applications (Parallels)/{8dcf6541-4642-4aa0-b6ef-f73b59c0005e} Applications.localized/Command Prompt.app
/Users/user-test/Applications (Parallels)/{9bfd84de-a9b0-445d-afd5-c95690c3d1ea} Applications.localized/Command Prompt.app
```

I am trying to filter this out (unsuccessfully):

```
    for index in "${!list_apps[@]}"
         do [[ ${list_apps[$index]} =~ '^(?!.*\(Parallels\)).*' ]] && unset -v 'list_apps[$index]'
     done
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote `unset -v 'list_apps[$index]'`. The single quotes prevent the varable _index_  from being expanded. Also, the single quotes on the RHS of the regex operator prevent the string from being interpreted as regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for index in "${!list_apps[@]}"; do
    [[ ${list_apps[index]} == *'(Parallels)'* ]] && unset 'list_apps[index]'
done
```

Because of the single quotes, `=~ '^(?!.*\(Parallels\)).*'` only matches strings that contain the *literal string* `'^(?!.*\(Parallels\)).*'` (no special meaning is given to `^`, `(`, `.`, etc.).  If you remove the quotes it still doesn't work because it uses regular expression features that aren't supported by Bash.

The code above uses Bash glob pattern matching to match strings that contain the literal string `(Parallels)`.

Comment: Why `index` and not `$index`? And then, consequently, double quotes (or no quotes) in the `unset` statement.

Comment: @user1934428, (non-associative) array indexes are a "math context" in Bash.  In a math context variable names can be used without preceding `$` symbols.  See [ArithmeticExpression - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).  I omit the `$` symbols in math contexts to de-clutter the code.

Comment: @user1934428, w.r.t. quoting, I always use single quotes except when expansions (`$...`)  are required in quoted strings.  That minimizes the risk of accidental expansions (e.g. because a string happens to have a `$` in it).  See [Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#unset_a.5B0.5D) for an explanation of why the quotes are necessary in `unset 'list_apps[index]'`.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware about the numeric context in array indexing. I think this will simplify some of my scripts.....